# Android: How to open the webview in a new screen

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I've got four Image Buttons in screen1.xml.
I've defined the webview in screen3.xml.
If i click the ImageButton1 or other buttons, the repective URL (in webview) should load in screen3.xml.

I tried to do this, but it throws forceclose error. But If I try the same this with webview defined in screen1.xml, it works. But the problem is the Image Buttons and the webview appears in the same page and they are overlapped which looks awful!

Please help me out to open the webview in a new screen.

BTW, can addView be used for this purpose?

```
public class click extends Activity 
{
 private WebView webView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        ImageButton i1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
        ImageButton i2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
        ImageButton i3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton3);
        ImageButton i4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton4);
 }
private void openBrowser1() 
     {

      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

      webView.loadUrl("myurl");
     }

public void myClickHandler1(View view) 
        {

         openBrowser1();
        }
```

Screen1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <WebView
android:id="@+id/web_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1.0" />



 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton1" android:clickable="true" android:onClick="myClickHandler1" 
 android:layout_width="130dip" android:background="@null" android:layout_height="130dip" android:layout_x="21dip" 
 android:layout_y="61dip" ></ImageButton>

 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton2" android:clickable="true" android:onClick="myClickHandler2" 
 android:layout_width="130dip" android:background="@null"  android:layout_height="130dip" android:layout_x="171dip" 
 android:layout_y="61dip" ></ImageButton>

 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton3" android:clickable="true" android:onClick="myClickHandler3" 
 android:layout_width="130dip" android:background="@null" android:layout_height="130dip" android:layout_x="21dip" 
 android:layout_y="241dip" ></ImageButton>

 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton4" android:clickable="true" android:onClick="myClickHandler4" 
 android:layout_width="130dip" android:background="@null"  android:layout_height="130dip" android:layout_x="171dip" 
 android:layout_y="241dip" ></ImageButton>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

screen3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >                 

<WebView
android:id="@+id/web_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1.0" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need some fix to your code...

```
public class click extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);        
        ImageButton i1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
        ImageButton i2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
        ImageButton i3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton3);
        ImageButton i4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton4);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.reforma.com");

        //Add a listener to ImageButton1
        i1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openBrowser1();
            }           
        });                             

    }

    private void openBrowser1() 
    {       
       //this intent is used to open other activity wich contains another webView
        Intent intent = new Intent(click.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }

}
```

screen1.xml

```
  <WebView
android:id="@+id/web_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />

 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton1" android:clickable="true"  
 android:layout_width="130dip" android:layout_height="130dip" android:layout_x="21dip" 
 android:layout_y="61dip" ></ImageButton>

 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton2" android:clickable="true"  
 android:layout_width="130dip" android:layout_height="130dip" android:layout_x="171dip" 
 android:layout_y="61dip" ></ImageButton>

 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton3" android:clickable="true"  
 android:layout_width="130dip" android:layout_height="130dip" android:layout_x="21dip" 
 android:layout_y="241dip" ></ImageButton>

 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton4" android:clickable="true"  
 android:layout_width="130dip"  android:layout_height="130dip" android:layout_x="171dip" 
 android:layout_y="241dip" ></ImageButton>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Add a new activity wich contains your webview where the webpage should be load!.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen3);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.reforma.com");         

    }

 }
```

screen3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >                 

<WebView
android:id="@+id/web_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Add to your AndroidManifest.xml your second Activity

```
   <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
          android:label="SecondActivity"/>
```

and you must have Internet permission to load the web page...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

any doubts???

Jorgesys

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. Like Jorgesys said, i tried to find what's wrong in my code. I have to add this line "  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);        " in to openbrowser1() method. Also I have to remove the "webview" attributes from screen1.xml. This is the reason why, i was getting FC when I tried to load the webview in screen 3.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're inflating and loading the screen3.xml layout anywhere, so attempts to reference the WebView it contains will probably generate an exception.  Sounds like what you really want to do is define another Activity for the webview layout and swap to it when the user pushes one of the buttons. See the 2nd part of the Notepad sample for a description of how to add additional Activities to an application and swap between them:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html