# load web view in an activity by clicking a button

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

i want to click on a button and it open an activity with an web view.
main activity

```
package test.example.webviewtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent (Main.this,WebViewPage.class);
    intent1.putExtra("page1", "file:///android_asset/1.html");
    Main.this.startActivity(intent1);

    Button page2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent (Main.this,WebViewPage.class);
    intent2.putExtra("page2", "file:///android_asset/2.html");
    Main.this.startActivity(intent2);

}   
}
```

second activity

```
package test.example.webviewtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WebViewPage extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webviewpage);

    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null){
    String page1Url = extras.getString("page1");
    String page2Url = extras.getString("page2");
    if (page1Url != null)
    mWebView.loadUrl(page1Url);
    else if (page2Url != null)
    mWebView.loadUrl(page2Url);
    }
}

}
```

in main activity no problem but in second one, mWebview in 3 place eclipse give me error.
what should i do for solve this problem.

Comment: are you able to compile the WebViewPage class? Where you declare the mWebView attribute?

Answer (score 1):

change that line

```
mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

to this

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides you a solution for loading webview in an activity by clicking a button.

[Android: How to open the webview in a new screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857303/android-how-to-open-the-webview-in-a-new-screen)